# external changing implementation of class

Tags: c#, reflection, dependency-injection, interface, partial-classes

Is there a way to change implementation of given class from outside? For example, I have the following implementation:

```
 public partial class Test
{
    public Interface1 Field = new Class1();
}
public interface Interface1
{
    //implementation    
}
public class Class1 : Interface1
{
    //implementation
}
```

I would like to define another class:

```
public class Class2 : Interface1
{
    //implementation
}
```

and change Test.Field to be object of Class2 class. I cannot modify implementation of Test class. I can only add another file with its partial implementation. I cannot also use any dependency injection libraries.

Comment: In your example `Field` is writable then you're free to do it. If it's not then...you MAY use Reflection but there are not guarantees that it will work as expected (now and/or in future).

Comment: If `Test` is a partial class that doesn't have a constructor, then you can add a contructor in another file and overwrite the value of `Field` (field initializers are run before the class construtor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Test` is a partial class that doesn't have a constructor, then you can add a `Test()` contructor in another file and overwrite the value of Field (field initializers are run before the class construtor). Note that `Class1` will still be built, but the will be discarded. If creating a `new Class1` is a cheap operation, then there is no problem in "wasting" work, but if `new Class1` is very slow (perhaps because it reads 5gb of data from the disk), then it is "bad" to do it.

There is another wonderful trick with partial classes: if the `new Class1` isn't using fully specified names (names with full namespace) then if you do

```
partial class Test 
{ 
    // Your Class1 (technically Test.Class1)
    // that is distinct from the other Class1
    public class Class1 : Interface1 { } 
}
```

then the `new Class1()` will "point" to *your* `Class1` because the naming resolution works that way.